# Empty Sidebar on Visual Studio Code on File -> Open

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, macos-sierra

I have been using Visual Studio Code for sometime and its really amazing so far. But often I stumble upon an issue where if I import project through **File->Open** I end up with empty sidebar. If I do `cmd+P` to load files, files are available but its just not visible on sidebar.

Trying open projects with **File->Open Recents** or **Ctrl+R** also dint work out.

[image: Here is the screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

After reporting the issue to Visual Studio Code's github [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37693), they have resolved the issue pretty fast.

#### Reason

Users who had file explorer hidden in 1.15 release might not see file explorer and also cannot retrieve it after upgrading to latest version. Workaround is to upgrade to insiders containing the fix or clear cache for that folder as follows:

#### Steps

1. Close the window opening the folder that has this issue
2. Open new empty Window
3. Run command `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`
4. Go to `Application` Tab in Developer tools
5. Select `file://` under `Local Storage` section in the menu on the left
6. Search for the key `workbench.explorer.views.state` using Filter inputbox
7. Select the folder with this key and Delete it
8. Now open the folder in VS Code and you should be seeing the file explorer.